# pg_search: how to prioritize exact word matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg-search

**Probem:** When searching texts with multiple occurrences of words similar to the search query they get higher rank than texts with one exact match.

**Example:** Say search query is *"productivity"*, then *"production of organic products"* gets higher rank than *"labour productivity"* just because it contains two similar words, though no exact word matches.

**Question:** What's the best way to prioritize records that have exact matches?

Here's my pg_scope:

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
                  :against => {
                    :title => 'A',
                    :search_string => 'B'
                  },
                  :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                      :dictionary => 'english',
                      :any_word => 'true'
                    }
                  }
```

Thx.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Kathan I didn't find a proper solution. I ended up applying an exact match order in my query .select(Dataset.arel_table[:title].matches("%#{q}%").to_sql << 'as exact_match').order('exact_match desc').search(q) But if I was doing it again I would not use pg_search and use elastic search instead https://www.elastic.co/

Comment: You could check out fuzzystrmatch and use levenshtein to give check for exactness https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can manipulate the search query, have a look around at [cover density ranking (`ts_rank_cd()` instead of `ts_rank()`) and its `normalization` parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING).

```
SELECT v, ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', v), to_tsquery('english', 'productivity')) rank,
       ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', v), to_tsquery('english', 'productivity')) rankcd,
       ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', v), to_tsquery('english', 'productivity'), 4) rankcd4,
       ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', v), to_tsquery('english', 'productivity'), 6) rankcd6
FROM (
  VALUES ('production of organic products'::TEXT),
         ('labour productivity'),
         ('labour productivity with more unrelated words'),
         ('labour productivity with more unrelated words and again production'),
         ('production of productivity'),
         ('product production')
) d(v)
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2402)

However, I'm not sure how to set up `pg_search_scope` with custom `normalization`.

Alternatively, you might be interested in [`trigram`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) [searches](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#searching-using-different-search-features) as well, they offer more exact (character by character) results.